# how to select query using two tables with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, Table A for Student_Record and Table B for Student_Subject linked by the Student_ID field.

```
Table A (Student_Record)
Student_ID | Name  | School_Year
1          | Jane  | 2010-2011
2          | Amy   | 2010-2011
3          | Dave  | 2011-2012
4          | Roger | 2010-2011
```

```
Table B (Student_Subject)
Student_ID | Subject | Grade
1          | Math    | Passed
1          | Physics | Passed
1          | History | Passed
2          | Math    | Failed
2          | Physics | Passed
2          | History | Passed
3          | Math    | Passed
3          | Physics | Passed
3          | History | Passed
4          | Math    | Passed
4          | Physics | Passed
4          | History | Passed
```

Based on the sample table above, I want to select the students enrolled in 2010-2011 and who passed all the subjects. 
The result should return **Jane** and **Roger** because they passed all their 3 subjects and are enrolled in 2010-2011 compared to **Amy** which Failed on Math and **Dave** whose school_year is 2011-2012.

Comment: OK so what do you think we can do? Did u look at join?

Comment: Yes I did look up SQL join, INNER JOIN to be specific, but it does not give the result I wanted or its just I am missing something in my query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sr.Student_ID, sr.Name
from Student_Record sr
left outer join Student_Subject ss on sr.Student_ID = ss.Student_ID 
    and ss.Grade = 'Failed'
where ss.Student_ID is null
    and sr.School_Year = '2010-2011'
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b0e3/2)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, where we will do your homework for you.

Comment: @RedFilter, thanks for the answer but this does not return anything?

Comment: @paynet Tell that to my SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: @JSKNS I hope I passed the exam ;)